# Lucene/Solr performance issue with large number of clauses

Tags: performance, solr, lucene

We are using Solr 4.3 (2 shard and 2 replica) for storing data. The query execution takes around 10 sec when there is lots of conditions on a field (around 100000 clauses), including phrase queries and rows=1000. I do return only id's though.

```
Collection: Documents
Fields: id,Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
Query: Field11:(value1 value2 value3..............value100000)
SortField: Field2
```

During analysis we found that following statement of (IndexSearcher.java class) takes most of the time.

Weight weight = query.createWeight(this);

We don't want any relavance/Scoring. So can we disable this feature Weight/scroting etc to improve the performance? if yes, How can we do this?

Please let me know any further information required on this.

Comment: In short: No way. You are working against Solr's sweet spot. What is your use case to do such a thing? Joining across cores, Security Filter, Checking whose friends are online, etc.

Comment: we have document management system. we are storing documentid and folderid (in which document belongs to)....For applying ACL to solr query we need to write below query. Query: Field11:(value1 value2 value3..............value100000)

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you want to apply ACLs there is, as far as I know, no ready to go solution. Therefore you will need to build your own.

How this is done can be read here [Custom Security Filtering in Solr: Based on Access Control Lists](http://java.dzone.com/articles/custom-security-filtering-solr).